How to verify/test POST operation with curl to thttpd?
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10). I setup a thttpd web server in my system, and want to test it with curl utility.
The /etc/thttpd.conf is as follows,
dir=/var/www/data
cgipat=**.cgi
logfile=/var/www/logs/thttpd_log
pidfile=/var/run/thttpd.pid

And I copied the index.html from thttpd project, and put it into /var/www/data.
I haved valiated that HTTP GET operation can work with curl -O http://192.168.0.22/index.html.
Now I want to verify/test the HTTP POST operation with curl, such as uploading a file to the HTTP server, but I don't know what should I do to setup and execute the verification.
Following command got an error,
# curl -XPOST -d b=@/1.text 192.168.0.22
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>501 Not Implemented</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#cc9999" text="#000000" link="#2020ff" vlink="#4040cc">

    <h2>501 Not Implemented</h2>
The requested method 'POST' is not implemented by this server.
    <hr>

    <address><a href="http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/">thttpd/2.29 23May2018</a></address>

  </body>

</html>

Updated with C-CGI test
Thanks to Jim, I did a test with CGI in C as follows.
Firstly, I got a simple C program as hello.cgi from https://blog.csdn.net/Zhu_Zhu_2009/article/details/87797884,
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *szGet = NULL;
  char szPost[256] = {0};

  printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");

  szGet = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  if (szGet != NULL && strlen(szGet) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", szGet);
    return 0;
  }
  printf("get--post\n");  

  gets(szPost);
  if(strcmp(szPost, "") != 0)
    printf("%s\n",szPost);

  return 0;
}

Then, I updated the index.html as follows,
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <form action="hello.cgi" method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="theText">
                        <input type="submit" value="Continue">
                </form>
        </body>
</html>

After re-started thttpd, I can access the embedded system through webbrowser. I entered some texts into the browser and clicked continue button, I got followings in the browser.
get-post theText=Hello world

So, I think the POST is working ??
Then I tried the curl -XPOST -d b=@/1.text 192.168.0.22, but I still got the same 501 error.
What did I miss here?

Do you have a CGI script that will handle that POST request? If not, what response other than 50x are you expecting?

If you speak (or at least read) PHP, you might gain insight from reading the $_POST man page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Is there any example of CGI script that I can refer to? I am not quite sure if I can run PHP in my embedded Linux system.

The PHP web server isn't the embedded system, you'd set that up termporarily on any spare machine that's handy.  Then you submit POST transactions from the embedded machine using curl and use PHP on the test server to inspect the $_POST array and see exactly what data the embedded system is sending.  You could do the same thing with Perl/CGI if you prefer.
